# Two usernames for Openerp db and PgAdmin db

Tags: postgresql, odoo, pgadmin

When I have create a DB using PGAdmin it creates the db under administrator as the user. then again I created a DB using Openerp frontend it creates the db under openerp as the user.

I only need one user wich both parties can access. How to do so ? when ever I tried to connect as openerp it asks for password which I didn't have. Please help me with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the configuration file of your Odoo, and inside it you will see a parameter named `db_user` (it will have `openerp` as its value). Its password will be set in `db_password` parameter. There you can know the password of the user `openerp` or even you will be able to modify both user and password to whatever you want.

Comment: you means in that openerp-server.config file ? Yep I had a look at it and it also have the "administrator" as a user, but how come there is a "openerp" user be there also ?

Comment: Thank you so much, that was the issue, there was two different users for openerp and postgres. I fixed it . Thanks again n' again